# Alarm Keeps Turning Off By Itself

Tags: alarm

I set 3 alarms in the morning and they all keep turning themselves off. Is this a common problem and/or is there a fix?
Edit: It's a galaxy note 9 and the alarms do not ring. Doesn't matter what volume my phone and its various sound settings are set to, doesn't matter that I have them on a weekday repeat timer, some days the alarms just refuse to function.

My phone will "behave" for a few days then do this for seemingly no reason. It started some months ago and its gotten to where I've gone from setting the one alarm, to two, to three, and they're all turning off. Today it actually gave me notifications though. Half an hour before each alarm I got a silent notification asking if I wished to turn them off. I was asleep so I obviously didn't see them or interact with my phone. I'm lucky I woke up with enough time to rush and get to work.

Comment: Could you mention the device model and Android version? By "turning themselves off", did you mean the alarms ring but stop automatically (check for the Clock's setting, there may be a setting for "silence after" for the alarm), or they don't ring at all (e.g. [killed by the system](https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung))?

Comment: Are you using Google Alarm/Clock app? See related bug that may still be present in your device. https://www.xda-developers.com/google-clock-alarm-bug/

Comment: I edited the question. Galaxy note 9, and the alarms never ring.